# Using Java Profilers To Investiage Code Within a Method

Tags: java, jprofiler

I know that I can use JProfiler to pinpoint methods which are potential bottle neck. But is it also possible to use JProfiler to investigate code within a particular method and see what part of the code within that method is causing the method not to perform well.

Thanks,
Cyrus

Comment: "perform well" is a broad subject, first drill down its meaning to memory, CPU or IO and then try to match insights from profiling on these..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the section that you want to be profiled and put it into an own method that you call from your original one.

Other than that, there will be no good way to do what you want, so: refactor your code.